# Cordova plugin whitelist error causes meteor (and then mup) to fail

Tags: meteor, mup

When running a meteor.js app via `meteor run --verbose android` I get this error:

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Cannot find plugin.xml
for plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist". Please try adding it again.
```

I've tried the fix suggested [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) (installed cordova plugin via `add cordova-plugin-whitelist` in the folder `.meteor/local/cordova-build`) and this got the emulator started but then this error appeared:

```
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I found some information about this one [on the issues gitHub site for meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8096), but I'm at a loss now for what to do.

These errors (not surprisingly) also cause meteor-up deployment to fail. I 
 tried adding `buildOptions: { "serverOnly": true }` to the mup.json file per the [mup docs](https://zodern.github.io/meteor-up/docs.html) but this failed to stop meteor from building the cordova architecture. Is there is a build setting or flag for `mup deploy` or `meteor build` so that it doesn't try to build the web.cordova architecture at all?

Comment: Remove the android platform from your project, that should do it

Comment: I tried that already. It now fails with a buffer error for a node module that's necessary for the application to work properly:

`buffer.js:69
      throw new Error(
      ^

Error: If encoding is specified then the first argument must be a string
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:69:13)
    at Readable.<anonymous> (~/meteor-up/node_modules/archiver/lib/util/index.js:32:15)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Readable.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)`

Comment: You might need to clear out meteor's build area as well, I think `rm -rf .meteor/local/cordova-build` or you can even `rm -rf .meteor/local`. You can do an npm rebuild as well, or `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: Fixed it. All errors appear to be linked to the original issue... thanks for the suggestions... I added `cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0` to `.meteor/cordova-plugins` file and this allowed it to build with this warning:
`WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0, but it should have a minimum version of 1.3.0 to ensure compatibility....`